# How to recover permanant deleted files from ext4

Tags: files, data-recovery

hey Guys I am kind of new in ubuntu and I need help. i permanently deleted my important files and I need to recover them. Please tell how to recover files in GUI way or command line way . thanks :)

Comment: Restore from your backup?

Comment: I have no backup :(

Comment: Any chance you have is a) stop using that disk **now** b) boot from a recovery CD and c) follow instruction in the duplicate link or search for "linux rescue disk" Good luck (and use this experience to learn to do backups.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15761/recover-data-like-a-forensics-expert-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/) can help you. Basically you need to install one or more data recovery programs in a terminal or with Synaptic Package Manager, The programs are **testdisk**,  **scalpel** and/or **foremost**. Code:

```
 sudo apt-get install testdisk scalpel foremost
```

Use the detailed instructions from the provided link to learn how to recover your lost/deleted data.

Comment: Add more info to your answer and put the link as reference.